# Sending Recipients details Through Variable - Send Grid

Tags: python, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a python script which is generating file and generating variables like from address , to_Address and mail content . I am passing these variables to another python scripts . where the TO_Address is not working and i am getting

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

If i hard code the value in the mail python code , I am able to receive the email

I am generating variable like below

```
to_address = '[To('+ "'"+'test1"example.com'+"'),"+'To('+ "'"+'test2"example.com'+"')"+']'
```

and passing to another python script

```
to_emails = to_address
from_email = from_address
subject = subject
content = mail_content

message = Mail(
  from_email = from_email,
  to_emails = to_emails,
 

 subject = subject,
  html_content = content,
  is_multiple=True
)
```

Here I am getting

```
{'from': {'email': 'test@example.com'}, 'subject': 'Test Email', 'personalizations': [{'to': [{}]}],
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Where as, if I hard code the same value in mail job, I can able to get the email

```
to_emails = [To('test1@example.com'),To('test2@example.com')]
from_email = from_address
subject = subject
content = mail_content

message = Mail(
  from_email = from_email,
  to_emails = to_emails,
  subject = subject,
  html_content = content,
  is_multiple=True
)
```

How do pass the variable to another job and make it email work using variables?

Comment: maybe first use `print(to_emails, to_address)`, `print(type(to_emails), type(to_address))`  to see what you created. In `to_address` you created string with text `"[To(...), To(...)]"` but in original `to_emails` you have list with two objects `To()`. You create it in totally wrong way. Better send only emails from one script to another - don't send `"[To(...), To(...)]"` OR you should create it in the same way `to_address = [To('test1@example.com'),To('test2@example.com')]`

Comment: how do you pass variables to other script? Do you use `import` ?

Comment: Thanks @furas , the variable which i am passing is <class 'str'> and the original to_email type is <class 'list'> , so i need to covert this str to list.  and i am using Matillion to pass the variable from one job to another . *you should create it in the same way to_address = [To('test1@example.com'),To('test2@example.com')]* - Tried with that method also same error.

Comment: Just changed my input variable as plain string and another job i have converted as List and now its working fine :)  Thanks a lot for your help .

Comment: I never used sendgrid but it seems it send it as text so I would send string only with mails (separated by `;`) - `to_address = "test1@example.com;test2@example.com"` and in other script I would use `split(";")` to create list with mails `parts = to_address.split(';')` and  later I would use this list in `to_emails = [To(parts[0]), To(parts[1])]`

Comment: its an existing code , i just planned to make a unique component for zipping and adding password and sending emails to all our modules. here they used send grid . But for zip i have used the subprocess where i am facing issue now when its comes to multiple file :(